# C# Hashtable problem

Tags: c#, collections

i dont know what's the problem with this code.. it says string cannot be converted to object.. something like that..

```
//lvLogs <-- ListView (2 colums)    

Hashtable serverLogs = new Hashtable();

        serverLogs.Add("a", "aw");
        serverLogs.Add("b", "ew");
        serverLogs.Add("c", "iw");

        foreach (DictionaryEntry h in serverLogs)
        {
            lvLogs.Items.Add(h.Key).SubItems.Add(h.Value);                
        }
```

but this code works fine..

```
Hashtable serverLogs = new Hashtable();

        serverLogs.Add("a", "aw");
        serverLogs.Add("b", "ew");
        serverLogs.Add("c", "iw");

        foreach (DictionaryEntry h in serverLogs)
        {
            //lvLogs.Items.Add(h.Key).SubItems.Add(h.Value);
            //lvi.SubItems.Add(h.Value);
            lvLogs.Items.Add(h.Key + "   -   " + h.Value);
        }
```

how can i separate the key and value from the columns in lvLogs?

Comment: use Key.ToString() and Value.ToString(). But Dictionary<string, string> is better as others suggest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Hashtable` is not a strongly typed collection. `DictionaryEntry.Key` returns an `object`, and you're trying to use it as a `string` without a cast, which isn't allowed.

The reason the string concatentation works is that *does* accept `object` as an argument (it calls `ToString()` on it).

Try using `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.

Comment: Note that `h.Key + "   -   " + h.Value` operation implicitly converts h.Key and h.Value objects to strings.

Comment: The string concat operation `+` gets compiled to calls to various overloads of `String.Concat`, which call `ToString()` on `object` arguments.

Answer (score 4):

First order of business, drop the `Hashtable`. The classes in the `System.Collections` namespace are obsolete and have been replaced by equivalents in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Use a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.